# bootstrap + jade checkbox

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, pug

Folks,
  Im quite new to jade and bootstrap.  Creating a simple form, which has dropdowns and checkboxes.

Right now my code looks as follows:

```
form(role="search",action='/uri/blah' method='post').navbar-form.navbar-left
    .form-group 
        input(type="name", name="bae", placeholder="bae", required).form-control
        select(id="type",name="type").form-control
            option(value="foo") foo
            option(value="bar") bar
            option(value="baz") baz
        input(type="text", name="X", placeholder="X", required).form-control
        input(type="checkbox", name="checkboxname", text="asdf").form-control
    p           
    button(type="submit").btn.btn-default Submit
```

Questions:
    1.) Checkbox name, whats the proper syntax to label it?
    2.) How to make the form more dynamic?  Ie, if a checkbox is clicked or a dropdown is selected, another would appear?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, in order to make it dynamic, you can't do it in Jade. You would have to rely on jQuery or other front-end libraries to handle that.

I label my Checkbox like this:

```
label(for="checkbox")
  input(type="checkbox", name="checkboxname", value="value").form-control
  | Checkbox Label Goes Here
```

If I want to set default values from the server:

```
label(for="checkbox")
  input(type="checkbox", name="checkboxname", value="value" checked=data.checked?"checked":undefined).form-control
  | Checkbox Label Goes Here
```

Comment: However, the `| content` after a p tag must be indented, whereas here it isn't? This is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The following works: (bootstrap3)

```
.checkbox
    label
    input(type='checkbox', name='checkbox', value='test')
    |   check
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using angular this works fine

```
    input(type="checkbox", name="myCheckbox")
    label(translate="TRANSLATE_TEXT", for="myCheckbox")
```